# why is @state being reset after alert dismissal

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

complete SwiftUI beginner here. I'm looking at this example and I'm trying to understand the lifecycle of `@state` variables.

`showingAlert` is initialized as `false` and is set to `true` when the button is tapped.
the part that I have trouble wrapping my head around is why does it reset back to `false` when the alert is dismissed? I do not set that to `false` anywhere.

I expected it to remain `true`

```
@State private var showingAlert = false

var body: some View {
   Button(action: { self.showingAlert = true }
   ) { 
     Text("Show Alert")
   }
   .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
     Alert(title: Text("Important message"))
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because, by definition, if the alert is dismissed, the alert is no longer presented. `$showingAlert` is a *binding* — it moves data in both directions. Its value is *always* correlated to whether the alert is being presented; that's what it means to be a binding.

Comment: right! so on dismissal the alert function automatically sets `$showingAlert` to false?